# How to enable CORS on Tomcat Web Server Version 6

Tags: web-services, tomcat, cors

am trying to enable CORS on Tomcat Web Server, as i have only got Filter information for Tomcat 7 and above, i need to know how can we configure Tomcat Server Version 6 for CORS.

I appreciate for your Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a custom valve when you want to set CORS headers on container level (see https://devdanke.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/how-to-set-http-header-in-tomcat-valve/) or use filters (http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html, http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggested links. Since am very new to these may i ask you what does is meant by "set CORS headers on container level", and where actually i caan find out addHeader() function.

Comment: Webapp filters work on application/deployment level whereas valves can affect the whole tomcat container. It depends on what you want to control. You can look here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html for the servlet api. One more thing if you use REST Easy: REST Easy resets HTTP headers before response.